# Return ID after insert with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, using

i know there are numerous topics already concerning this, since i googled it already but none of them can fit/work with my code as far as i can see.  I simply want to return an Auto Generated ID form my database after an insert. This is a part of my code:

```
    using (***LINQDataContext dc = new ***LINQDataContext())
    {
        dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(new User
        {
            Username = user,
            Password = EncryptPassword(user, pass, 1, null, null),
            Email = email
        });

        dc.SubmitChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You will need to raise your `new User...` to a local variable of the `using` statement so you have access to it after you `SubmitChanges()`

Comment: You meant `HashPassword`, right? (ducks)

Comment: Naah EncryptPassword is a password hashing function i use.

Comment: but if you are using Linq-2-sql, you might want to return the user instead of the ID...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var newUser = new User {
    Username = user,
    Password = EncryptPassword(user, pass, 1, null, null),
    Email = email
};
dc.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
dc.SubmitChanges();
// any identity / rowversion properties should now have values
var id = newUser.Id;
```